# Restore game progress state before Facebook connection

Tags: candy-crush-saga, facebook

My girlfriend has an Android phone and plays Candy Crush Saga. She was level 140 on her phone and level 20 on Facebook. Both game states were not connected!

However, she decided to **connect her Android candy crush with Facebook**, which **synced the Facebook state of the game to the phone**. She is now level 20 in both states which is pretty sad.

**How can we get the game state back to level 140?**

Disconnecting from Facebook did not solve the problem.

I don't think she backed up her phone at any point.

Comment: meanwhile...my girlfreind played even further than she was before... :D

Answer (score 2):

The only way to get back to level 140 now is to keep playing until you reach 140. In other words, you lost the phone game state and cannot get it back.

The good news is you can easily get back to 140 by playing it on the phone. If she is really desperate, she can change the date/time on her phone to keep getting lives. She can then sync with facebook (if not already synced), then clear data on the phone version, set date back to normal date, sync with facebook again to get the progress back on the phone.

Comment: she reached level 140 5 days after is asked the question ;)

Comment: Just wait until she gets to level 700+, the game becomes a pain